# QSpinBox prevent the user from enternig thousand separators

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

In a QSpinBox, when the range is sufficient, the user is allowed to enter thousand separators.
Eg: 1.2.3.4 is a valid entry, en then [fixup()](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qspinbox.cpp#n574) just removes the dots. Resulting in 1234.

How can I prevent the user from entering thousand separators?

Previously I made something similar based on QLineEdit which uses validators.
But QAbstractSpinbox doesn't use QValidators. So I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override `validate` and reject input if contains undesired character.

It could be something like that:

```cpp
QValidator::State MySpinBox::validate(QString &input, int &pos) const
{
    if (input.contains(ThousandSeparator)) {
        return QValidator::Invalid;
    }
    return QSpinBox::validate(input, pos);
}
```

Please do not be to greedy what user can and can't do, since to restrictive rules are annoying for the end user.

`validate` is called whenever content changes. `fixup` is called when value should be committed (widget losses focus or enter is pressed) and must be able to transform input from intermediate state to valid.

Comment: Ah I have to return invalid, and I forgot the const :(, that why it didn't work at first... Thank you! The reason I need this is because the ability to insert "." is unclear to the user when these boxes are mixed between doublespinboxes. You can enter "12.5" and click Ok on the dialog and 125 is saved. Not what the user expects to happen...

Comment: use `override` keyword (since C++11) to catch this kind of problems.